# When changing DROPDOWN 1, need to auto select an option from the DROPDOWN 2 and make it readonly, using JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, yii

When changing ***DROPDOWN 1***, need to get the id and auto select an option from the ***DROPDOWN 2*** and make it readonly, using JQuery.

**DROPDOWN 1** ===========

```
<div id="div_post_code" class="row text-label w250 inline " style="display: block;">
<?php echo CHtml::activeLabelEx($cssAtapsClient, 'suburb_id')."\n";?>
<?php $this->widget('application.components.SAutoComplete', array('width'=>200,
                'model'=>$cssAtapsClient, 'parseData'=>true, 'matchContains'=>true,
                'attribute'=>'suburb_id', 'data'=>$postCode, 'ddindicator'=>true,
                'max'=>50,
                'multipleSeparator'=>false
              )); ?>        
</div>
```

**DROPDOWN 2** ===========

```
<div id="div_state" class="row text-label w250 inline " style="display: block;">
    <?php echo CHtml::activeLabelEx($cssAtapsClient, 'state_id') ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::activeDropDownList($cssAtapsClient, 'state_id', CHtml::listData($stateList, 'id', 'state'), array('empty'=>'- - Select State - -','id'=>'state_id', 'class'=>'long')); ?> 
</div>
```

[image]

**Question**

using "change()" function in js is not working as expected.

**//Load State to dropdown 2**

```
   $('#CSSAtapsClient_suburb_id_input').change(function() {

}
```

**Edited**
I have created a jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/wtYW6/4/

screenshot -> got via firbug
[image]

Comment: put your code in jsfiddle and show what is not working

Comment: @shareek yes can u pls create a jsfiddle and show it..

Comment: are you sure that the widget('application.components.SAutoComplete') use an input tag?

Comment: @iBlue
I have created a jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/wtYW6/1/

Comment: @ShareekAhamed u said there are 2 drop downs..all i see is one input text and a drop down....

Comment: @iBlue actually the first one is a customized dropdown, which is actually a "textbox" 
I am attaching a screenshot -> got via firbug

Comment: @BuDen i have added a screenshot -> got via firbug

Comment: @ShareekAhamed check fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YupfA/1/)

Answer (score 2):

ok here is the modified code

```
    $('#postcode').change(function () {
    if ($('#postcode').val() == 0) {
        $('#state').prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
        $('#state').prop("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

You were missing a few things...

1) your were selecting using `Id` and were not using `#`  like  `$('postcode')` should be `$('#postcode')`

2) Its `$('#postcode').val()` and not `$('postcode').val`

3) And no need for `()` in`$('#state').prop("disabled", true)()`

Here is the working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wtYW6/3/)

Comment: oh there were some issues in my fiddle
'#' sorry for that...
but the question is not that..!

Q: when changing the number in the textbox -> need to apply it to the dropdown accordingly.
and more over if the value in text box is '0' then the dropdown should be disabled.


and another thing..
the js link is the same as I sent you..
you should press the update button and create a new fiddle :)

Comment: Now disabling is working thanks :)
http://jsfiddle.net/wtYW6/3/

but how to select dorpdown 2 value which is entered in the text box.

Comment: dats the link....its working.....if its not working for you, den i'm assuming that after entering 0 in text box you are not losing focus on text for the change code to execute

Comment: @ShareekAhamed where is the drop down 2?

Comment: @BuDen good for u and the time when u posted the fiddle and i answered the question is same ....

Comment: i upvoted your answer which is great. I just propose to @Shareek watch my solution )